# Shortcut keys for commands in Gnome Terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

What I need are buttons in my Gnome Terminal to which I can assign commands I want, so when I click on the specific button, a command is executed in a terminal tab I'm at.

I've been looking for this all over the internet for the past few months and was unable to find it. And I really not even know how do I search for this I always find irrelevant results...

Comment: Terminals don't implement this functionality. The reason is: A terminal doesn't "know" what is happening inside, doesn't know whether you're at the shell prompt (and if so, whether you already have some piece of text typed, even moved the cursor around, or entered a special mode), or if you're running whatever external command. There's no "real" way for the terminal to ask the shell to execute that command, it could only pretend to "type" (or paste) it, which is harmful in any other context than a prompt followed by the empty command line.

Comment: But it doesn't need to know. I have seen a similar thing on Windows. 
I just want instead of manually typing same things, or copying them on the file, to have them 'pasted' on click of a button. :(

Comment: Any terminal _could_ easily provide this option, but if you clicked on it when in some special mode (e.g. Midnight Commander with the F9 menu open) it would invoke totally unexpected things. In this sense this feature would be dangerous and unreliable, that's why I assume terminals don't implement it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Thanks. I am just shocked there's no such extension for Gnome Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

[bash aliases](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Aliases_in_.bashrc)
You can set an alias for a command which is probably closest to what you're looking for , if I understand what you want.

Otherwise, something like Tmux might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, but I need this for servers I connect to remotely. So I need something independent from shell session.  :(

Comment: If it's ssh you can presumably just copy your local .bashrc config file with the alias's to the remote machine(assuming it's running bash). Not sure what platform or OS the remote machine is running though. Otherwise might look into either a bash script you can run locally or macros of some kind.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I wanna have 'button blocks' on my gnome-terminal window, and assign commands to them, so they are executed on click. This can only come in the form of a gnome extension or something.

Comment: You probably need a different terminal emulator then, something like Kitty( https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/# ) maybe.  Or to write an application with a gui interface.

Comment: Write a small utility that places the given text in the clipboard when you click on that button, then paste to the terminal.